# Please tell me this is not a new design that's staying in place

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Today, the design changed:

[image]

- **All** white
- Background grid reminiscent of subway tiles
- Conveys an appearance of a clean room or surgical bay
- Completely unfriendly, and uninviting.

The previous design had sort of a “lounge” atmosphere. This comes across as the *entire* opposite direction.

This design seems more suitable for a site for surgeons or microchip designers, not for artists. The site design should reflect *art* more than a "clean room" in my opinion.

Comment: Very much a bug. We're on it!

Comment: Oh thank heavens @AaronShekey  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed. More details can be found on [my answer over
on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377953/395497):

> This issue has been fixed. Short version: There was an upstream change in our [Stacks library](https://stackoverflow.design/) that caused the css specificity of the default theme to be higher than the network themes. As a result, the default theme was applied to all of the components (buttons, fonts, and so on) across the network. We put in a quick (but reliable) fix on the Stack Exchange-side of things while we look into addressing the root cause in Stacks.